# Optimising Delays on WebGL

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, delay, maya, unity-webgl

I am trying to develop an application with Maya and Unity (for multiplatform use) then exporting it to WebGL, but the load times for the application is quite long, although it is not a very large file. Is there a noticeable difference in performance if the models were created in another program (before being imported to unity), or if the application was developed natively in WebGL?

TLDR: Is there a performance difference for WebGL between Maya -> Unity -> WebGL and just WebGL?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the Unity WebGL pathway? That's officially "pre release", isn't?

Comment: I'm not sure, it could be "pre-release" but would that indicate that unity export is causing the application to load slower? As opposed to native WebGL?

Comment: I think the Unity WebGL clients are still in development, so there are a lot places it might not be optimized yet. WebGL perf is probably also dependent on browser and hardware considerations, but I don't know much about it. Have you tried chrome vs. IE vs Firefox testing?

Comment: I see, well I will try it on different browsers and see if theres a difference. I was just hoping that there wouldn't be a need to remake the application just to get decent performance. Thanks for the suggestion tho.

Comment: It seems Firefox is the has fastest load time. I noticed that when i run a simple WebGL app exported by unity for the first time, it takes noticeably longer than subsequent times to load, and is always slower than running from a js html build.

Comment: Dotnet stuff always has to be compiled to bytecode, which is why it has a reputation for slow startup times. It's possible that's the hangup. Depending on the way they did it that could be one-time cost or an every-time-you-start cost..

Answer (score 0):

As for the meat of your actual question, "Is there a performance difference for WebGL between Maya -> Unity -> WebGL and just WebGL?":

No, there isn't.

Unity imports models from Maya or whatever external source you author them in. Once imported, they are Unity assets in Unity's own internal format (a structure of vertices with positions, UV's, tangents, faces, etc.) This is the same format you would end up with if you were to manually create them directly in Unity or via script. Of course, some external applications might tend to create less optimal models in the first place, such as a high number of redundant vertices or unnecessarily high amounts of tessellation on some surfaces, but Maya is pretty good, and you can also choose to let Unity optimize your meshes to automatically patch up such problems.

But aside from these details of the model itself, no, it doesn't matter where they came from or that the target is WebGL, with respect to one authoring tool vs. another.